# Symfony2 Trailing Slash in route causes web debug toolbar routing error app_dev.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

For some reason, when I'm running my Symfony 2.5 applicaton in a Vagrant VM, if I have a trailing slash on the app_dev.php route, it breaks the web debug toolbar.

I think that in the .htaccess, I am not doing any redirect, since my URL is:

```
mysite.dev/app_dev.php/
```

I can remove the /, but the problem (er, annoyance) is that I have a route for "home" which is just "/". So if I have a link to "home", it goes to mysite.dev/app_dev.php/ instead of mysite.dev/app_dev.php

I have the default .htaccess and I've even tried adding a rule to remove a  trailing slash:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    # ADDED
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And the problem is ultimately "No route found for "GET //_wdt/dab5bd"

```
[2014-08-23 13:44:19] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET //_wdt/dab5bd" (from "http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/")" at /var/project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1977 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET //_wdt/dab5bd\" (from \"http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/\") at /var/project/app/cache/dev/classes.php:1977, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException: None of the routers in the chain matched this request\nGET /app_dev.php//_wdt/dab5bd HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept:           */*\r\nAccept-Encoding:  gzip,deflate,sdch\r\nAccept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.8\r\nConnection:       keep-alive\r\nCookie:           PHPSESSID=886nt3bqtnf5dqo6vpiq070ve4\r\nHost:             mysite.dev\r\nReferer:          http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/\r\nUser-Agent:       Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36\r\nX-Php-Ob-Level:   1\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n\r\n at /var/project/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/Symfony/Cmf/Component/Routing/ChainRouter.php:202)"} []
```

Is there some way around this?

Comment: I also have this problem, surprised no one posted an answer yet :(

Comment: The cause is actually using php-fpm in my case. I don't have the config in front of me (it's from PuPHPet though), but basically, it was breaking .htaccess. Switched from php-fpm fixed this.